# Manually installing/integrating a composer package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried installing this composer module on my Laravel app https://github.com/alihesari/laravel-social-auto-posting but im facing some issues. Im avoiding composer since it requires me to update my Laravel version which will break things (im runnin under 5.1.9).

Steps that I took so far:

1) `wget https://github.com/alihesari/laravel-social-auto-posting/archive/master.zip` - inside htdocs directory

2) unzipped master.zip and renamed folders. Moved folders inside /vendor/ folder under this structure: 
/vendor/toolkito/larasap/ - This folder contains the src subfolder as shown in the repo.

3) Added this reference in \vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php and in \vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php: `'Toolkito\\Larasap' => array($vendorDir . '/toolkito/larasap/src'),`

4) Configured my secret keys in the config file, for the proper social media connection

5) Added `use Toolkito\Larasap\SendTo;` in the main controller, as per repo's instructions

6) Added `SendTo::Twitter('Hello, I\'m testing Laravel social auto posting');` to a function that I use and ended up in this error:

```
FatalThrowableError in HomeController.php line 47:
Fatal error: Class 'Toolkito\Larasap\SendTo' not found
```

I also tried `use Vendor\Toolkito\Larasap\SendTo;` in step 5, and ended up with the same error message.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: if the package you are trying to install requires a higher version of laravel libraries what makes you think it will work with what you have? there are version constraints for a reason usually, they aren't just arbitrary (majority of the time)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the message I receive when trying to install it via composer: https://pastebin.com/vnWRkz03 Im not making any assumptions - I just believe that it would work fine by a manual installation aswell.

Comment: Really not sure if this will work, if the code inside `master.zip` _requires_ methods from say Laravel 5.6 that are not available or have a different syntax than your Laravel 5.1 this will just not work, no matter how you install it. What's wrong with upgrading to a higher or the latest Laravel version?

Comment: @kerbholz thats a custom app and things will break down upon upgrading. Nothing wrong, however, a lot of custom work needs to be done. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Personally I'd invest the time to make the app upgradable, when using old/outdated code you may be open to old vulnerabilites that have been fixed in newer versions of packages. Not sure how composer handles manually added packages, but you might have to do it all again when updating composer or trying to install a new package. Another option could be to fork that package and make the changes required to run on 5.1 and use your forked package. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Quick update: There's a comment in `\vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php`: "_// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer_". Made some changes in that file, ran `composer update` and all manual changes in that file are gone